# GPS tracking work on Android Marshmallow but always return 0 on lower API's

Tags: java, android, gps

I am making Android library for Unity3d for GPS tracking. It works great on my Marshmallow but i tried it on several lower devices and they are always getting 0 for any coordinate. What can be the problem here? I have tried both GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER and got same result. Maybe i'm missing some difference that i should make in code for older API's? My code:

```
package com.giganeo.gps;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PermissionInfo;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.location.Location;

import java.security.Permission;

public class GPSClass  {

    private Context context;
    private static GPSClass instance;
    private LocationManager locationManager = null;
    private static LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    private GPSClass(){
        instance = this;
    }

    public static GPSClass instance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new GPSClass();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void start(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
            if(context.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

    public double latitude() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (context.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getLatitude();
            }
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getLatitude();
            }
        }
        return 567;
    }

    public double longitude() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (context.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getLongitude();
            }
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getLongitude();
            }
        }
        return 567;
    }

    public double altitude() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (context.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getAltitude();
            }
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getAltitude();
            }
        }
        return 567;
    }

    public float horizontalAccuracy() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (context.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getAccuracy();
            }
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getAccuracy();
            }
        }
        return 567f;
    }

    public float verticalAccuracy() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (context.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getAccuracy();
            }
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getAccuracy();
            }
        }
        return 567f;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean isEnabledByUser(){
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (locationListener != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            locationListener = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use `requestLocationUpdates()` you should then handle the location updates in `onLocationChanged()`. Basically relying on `getLastKnownLocation()` is not a great idea although it may seem to work. (And there's a lot of unnecessary repetition in the code, but that's more of a stylistic issue.)

Comment: Repetition is out of despair. I can't use onLocationChanged because it is library for Unity3d. Also i'am trying to retrieve data every half second, i should see some changes. Maybe you have some other suggestions?